# How to use Apache Drill to work with sources in Excel documents and RDBMS at the same time?

Tags: mysql, excel, apache-drill

I have a RDBMS which is MySQL and several Excel files.

I need to query across both the RDBMS and the Excel files and I came across Apache Drill.

I understand that Apache Drill allows me to construct ANSI SQL queries on schemaless data sources like Excel.

Question, what if I need to query across Excel files *and* RDBMS data source at the same time?

Can I use Apache Drill?

if not, what can I use?

If I prefer to use Apache Drill, then what workarounds do I have to do to allow the Apache Drill to work with RDBMS?

Answer (score 0):

A solution for connecting to the RDBMS is coming soon. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-3180.